How can i return type when there's 2 different possibilities?
I have a problem while doing testing in SIT forward,
this forward is using old version of frontend and new version backend.
The structure of schema type is changing like this:
old backend:
type Product {
    productName: String
    productType: String
    prices: PriceList
}

type PriceList {
    id: String
    priceDate: String
    amount: Float
}

While in the new backend:
type Product {
    productName: String
    productType: String
    prices: PriceList
}

type PriceList {
    offset: Int
    limit: Int
    amount: Int
    items: [Price]
}

type Price {
    id: String
    priceDate: String
    currentPrice: Float
}

Here's the query:
productDetail(productCode: String!, filter: ProductFilter):Product!

I've tried to use union in GraphQL, here's union that i try to create:
union PricesUnion = [Price] | PriceList

when filter is not provided while querying, i should return array of price without pagination. but i can't use array of Price in union, based on docs it's only work when the type is object.
Is this possible to do that? please give me advice. thank you.

This is not a TypeScript solution, but normally you'ld create a new endpoint like /v2/graphql for breaking API changes.
